# P.S.D matrix is convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, optimal-control

Would any body explain me why a positive semidefinite matrix is a convex cone? how can we assume that a matrix is a cone? It is easy for me to think about e.g. two points which make a cone, but how about a matrix (or a vector)? 
As we know a cone is:"any combination as $x=\theta_1 *x_1 +\theta_2*x_2$ with $\theta_1 >=0$ and $\theta_2 >=0$  and a convex cone: any combination as $x=\theta_1 *x_1 +\theta_2*x_2$ adds a constraint $ \theta_1+\theta_2 =1$. Sorry, I'm new to convex.

Comment: A positive semidefinite matrix $A$ satisfies $v^\top A v \ge 0$ for any vector $v$. Use this definition along with the conditions for a convex cone to check that, for example, $\theta A$ is also PSD for any $\theta \ge 0$, and that $\theta_1 A + \theta_2 B$ is PSD for any PSD $A$ and $B$ with $\theta_1+\theta_2=1$ .

Comment: Thanks, how can we assume that a matrix is a cone? It is easy for me to think about e.g. two points which make a cone, but how about a matrix (or a vector)?

Comment: The statement should be "the **set** of PSD matrices is a convex cone."